# intersection of dense sequence with compact subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{x_k\}$ be a dense sequence in $\mathbb R^2$ and let $E$ be a a non-singleton compact connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Is $\{x_k\}\cap E$  a dense sequence of $E$?

Comment: What if $E$ is a single point set and $E\cap\{x_k\}=\emptyset$?

Comment: I fixed the question

Comment: I see you added "proper", but still, what if $E$ is a single point set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample put $\{x_k\}=\Bbb Q^2$ and $E=[0,1]\times\{\sqrt{2}\}$.